# Bash script ignores the negative prefix on negative numbers

Tags: bash, real-number

```
 a=4;
 b=7;
 c=5;

 x =[ a-b ] 
 if (x -gt c) then {
  echo "x  is  greater"

  } else {
  echo " something"
  }
```

I want to compare `x` and `c` ignoring the negative prefix of `c`.

Comment: You mean like comparing absolute values ? Also, why is your question tagged with `bash` when your code sample isn't a bash script ?

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: I don't think you're writing in bash man.

Comment: Negative prefix of c? Did you mean x?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you meant "negative prefix of **x**".  There are a ton of errors in your code, are you sure you're writing in bash?

```
#!/bin/bash

typeset a=4 b=7 c=5

x=$(( a - b ))
x=${x//-/}

if [[ x -gt c ]]; then
    echo "x  is  greater"
else
    echo " something"
fi
```

Comment: `bash` is actually very strongly typed; it simply has only *one* type: the string. In place of multiple types, it has distinct operators that *interpret* strings as different values. For example, `-gt` treats its arguments as integers, while `>` treats its arguments as strings.